# Why un-grammatical if no action verb precedes "in response to"?

Tags: grammaticality

What "verb" must precede **in response to**? Why **in response to** incorrect "without a verb"? I think authors made mistake, because "were" IS  a verb? Just not ACTION verb?

> **response,** as in **in response to**. This phrase is often used incorrectly without a verb, as in the following sentences: *The regulations were in response to the problem created by lack of definitions*. Rather, state that the regulations were enacted to resolve the problem. *Board Letter No. 829 was in response to an inquiry about disclosure of a security interest in all after-acquired property*. Rather, state that the letter addressed disclosure of a security interest.

Bahrych, Merino. *Legal Writing and Analysis in a Nutshell 5th edition* (2017). 375.

Comment: I agree that the phrasing is slightly faulty but the intention would be clear to most native speakers. The point is that, although 'to be' can be used on it's own as a main verb, the structure of the sentence is such that 'were' in the example appears to be working as an auxilliary verb but without a main verb present. The use of 'to be' as a free-standing main verb is much more restricted than it's use as an auxilliary.

Comment: Requirements for legal writing are stricter than for most other writing, as legal statements need to be unambiguous even when people are trying to misunderstand them.

Comment: In normal writing there's nothing wrong with "The regulations were in response to the problem created ...".

Comment: The customary verb has been eliminated by custom. It should be _The regulations were enacted in response to ..._ Nothing special here, and it's not limited to the phrase _in response to_; it would work much the same with a purpose infinitive, for instance: _The regulations were (enacted) to prevent mopery in the mezzanine_.

Comment: @JohnLawler "The regulations were to prevent ..." seems ambiguous to me. In addition to the meaning you intended, describing the regulations' purpose, it could also describe their effect. That is, it could mean that the regulations ended up preventing ..., regardless of their purpose --- in analogy with "was to" in contexts like "Alexander conquered everything in sight, yet his empire was to collapse shortly after his death."